# Perimeter of the square

Tags: geometry

[image]
How to find the perimeter of the square? This is the question from a 14 years old textbook, I can solve this by using vector. But they are just 14 years old, they won't learn vector at the age. Is there another way to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the two right angles we know that the 9cm line segment is parallel to the 3 cm segment.
Extend those segments and complete the rectangle.
Compute the length of the diagonal of the rectangle using Pythagoras' Theorem.

> 13

The diagonal of the rectangle is also the diagonal of the square, and another application of Pythagoras gives us the side of the square.

> $13\sqrt{2}\over 2$

Answer (score 1):

Using the theorem of Pythagoras.

Complete the $3\times5$ rectangle to get a larger rectangle triangle of sides $3+9$ and $5$, from one corner to the other.

Then the diagonal of the square is the hypothenuse,

$$\sqrt{12^2+5^5}=13.$$

At the same thime, the diagonal is the hypotenuse of the half-squares, i.e.

$$\sqrt{c^2+c^2}=\sqrt2c.$$